# Problema con el IDE Eclipse for Enterprise Java Developers ,se cuelga al cambiar entre las clases y es muy lento

Tags: eclipse, java-ee

Tengo instalado el Eclipse for  Enterprise Java Developers en la versión 4.15.0 y tengo el problema que cuando quiero cambiar entre clases el IDE se cuelga y tarda mucho tiempo en reaccionar , hay veces que es necesario matar el proceso y volver a ejecutar el IDE [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que te falta memoria RAM,  procesador, o ambas,  no hay solucion de Software para ello.

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes intentar es actualizar tus controladores,  depronto mejore un poco o bastante este problema.

Comment: Tengo una computadora que tiene 12 GB en RAM y el procesador es un i7 de octava generación, ,voy a tomar en cuanta tus recomendaciones muchas gracias   , una consulta mas que controladores debo actualizar ?@Riven

Comment: Definitivamente no es tu hardware... pasa que eclipse y los IDE de java se van llenando de basura conforme se van usando, y llega un punto en el que estan saturados de basura, a vecez tambien puede ser que haz instalado una version de 32 bits en un sistema de 64, es mejor tener eclipse de 64 bits en general, seria bueno intentar reinstalar eclipse y asegurar de que sea version 64 bits, tambien pues los controladores que deberias actualizar son los de la tarjeta grafica y la pantalla.

Comment: @Riven tomaré mucho en cuenta tus consejos para que mi IDE de eclipse mejore muchas  Gracias